# want to know the disadvantages of using state (this.state) react components (not redux)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

i just want to know this.whether state json object binding and normal json object binding is same or not? below is the example.

1st example

```
state = { name: "Default", email: "" };

binding data : this.state.name

this.setState({ name: e.currentTarget.value })
```

2nd example

```
const data= {name: "Default", email: ""}

binding data to control: data.name

onchange={e=>data.name=e.value}
```

both are working fine but want to know which one is better in performance?

my application dosent need any imutable data because i not displaying data dynamically i need to fetch the data from api on component load and posting the data to api on form submit. so i am using the 2nd approch. where i feel state will unnecessarly load render object.

so can any one suggest which one is better?

Comment: How is 2nd example working fine? If you use an object called data, how does React understand that it should re-render the component on onChange because you do not change state to tell React to re-render the ui because an input is entered. Do you see your input changes in the page?

Comment: hi, yes it wont rerender the component and i dont want my application to re render on control change. thats why i am using the second approch. by this only my json object will update and i am using the json on form submit. it am using mutated way

Comment: But when you type, do you see your typed value in the input?

Comment: yes. i can see the typed value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the state is not associated with any UI component then changing it will not re-render anything so functionally both will work the same.

In terms of performance 2nd approach will be faster as it is a direct object manipulation whereas calling setState is a function call and doesn't guarantee immediate execution.

However do not use 2nd approach at all because it will create confusion for the next developer who manages such code(In my opinion). In the long run when the data grows you will have to keep a separate state obj for managing the data and the UI.
So it is always better to keep them separate from the beginning.